# How to rotate glDrawArrays's object without matrices transformation?

Tags: java, opengl

Yo guys. I have heightmap and I want display it using buffer on video card and glDrawArrays. But I need to rotate it in clockwise direction on 90 degrees in array's building process. Without any matrices transformation.
Here is some code of data loading and array's build.

```
private void Import(String path) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)); //loading heightmap from binary file
        int resolution = (int)Math.sqrt(bytes.length/4); //figure out dimension of map (data has float type, that's why here is 4)
        float[] floats=new float[resolution*resolution]; //initialize an array that will contain the heights
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().get(floats); // transform byte array to float array

        for(int i = 0; i<floats.length; i++)
        {
            floats[i]=floats[i]*600f; // denormalize heights (max height == 600)
        }

        float step = 100/513f; //find a distance to be between points 100 - a map width, and 513 - the number of heights in its
        float optiStep=1; //some optimization~.. 

        fBuff = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(resolution*resolution*3*4/(int)optiStep); //create an array that will contain the coordinates of the vertices of quads

        for(int i =0; i<resolution-1; i+=optiStep)
        {
            for(int j =0; j<resolution-1; j+=optiStep) // some calculations
            {
                float x1=i*step,y1=floats[i*resolution+j],z1=j*step;

                float x2=i*step+step,y2=floats[(i+1)*resolution+j],z2=j*step;

                float x3=i*step+step,y3=floats[(i+1)*resolution+(j+1)],z3=j*step+step;

                float x4=i*step,y4=floats[i*resolution+(j+1)],z4=j*step+step;

                    fBuff.put(x1); // пихаю координаты вертексов квадов в тот массив
                    fBuff.put(y1);
                    fBuff.put(z1);

                    fBuff.put(x2);
                    fBuff.put(y2);
                    fBuff.put(z2);

                    fBuff.put(x3);
                    fBuff.put(y3);
                    fBuff.put(z3);

                    fBuff.put(x4);
                    fBuff.put(y4);
                    fBuff.put(z4);
            }
        }

        fBuff.rewind(); // translate carriage to zero position
    }
```

After that I have to create a buffer on video card.

```
 public void CreateBuffer(GL2 gl)
    {
        this.gl=gl;
        targetsBuffer = Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1);
        gl.glGenBuffers(1, targetsBuffer);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, targetsBuffer.get(0));
        gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fBuff.capacity()*Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT, fBuff, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
```

And then I have created method which will be called in the main function for display something.

```
public void Draw(){
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,targetsBuffer.get(0)); 
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0 );
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_QUADS, 0, fBuff.capacity() / 3);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
```

After that I can see needed image of object. But I need to rotate this object in clockwise direction. I guess, that I need to change something in array building cycle, but nothing helps.
So what I have to do for rotating my object?

Answer (score 0):

If your grid is orientated like the below

x1,y1,z1            x2,y2,z2

x4,y4,z4.           x3,y3,z3

And you wanted to rotate clockwise 90 degrees, you just assign the values differently

x4,y4,z4.          x1,y1,z1

x3,y3,z3.          x2,y2, z2

Comment: Yeah. Oke, I'll try it. But early I tried something like  4 3 2 1 instead of  1 2 3 4 and got same result

Comment: after few hours of procrastination I got it